# What to clean up in Webmaster Tools before taking down a website?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

I have a domain that will soon expire. I intend to take down my site and not renew the domain, but let it become available for others to buy.

I've had the site on Google Webmaster Tools for some time. Is there any information that I should remove from the Webmaster Tools? Any type of clean up I can do before the domain expires? The same question applies to Google Analytics.

I've previously purchased a domain that was owned by another person, and their email address was still listed under Users and Property Owners. I'd prefer to wipe this information if possible along with any other data.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best if you chose to delete the website from your search console. The reason for this is that if someone were to register the domain once it drops and put up a malicious/spam site on it, it's possible that the domain could be associated to you if it's still in your search console website listings.

You can delete a website on search console by clicking manage property->delete property in your dashboard.

Google will also unverify your ownership of the domain once it drops and it starts returning a 404. So this will naturally disassociate you with any malicious content that could happen to it after its change of ownership.